# post expire after x days

Tags: plugins, php, posts, loop

I want to create a code snippet for expiration of post after x days from the post published date, I tried with this code but I always displays the true condition, what am I doing wrong?

```
$pfx_date       = get_the_date('d/m/Y');
$datacorrente   = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-5 days"));

if ( $pfx_date <= $datacorrente ) { 
    echo 'post expired'; 
} else { 
    echo 'post open'; 
}
```

"-5 days" is the x days variable after the post is expired.

Comment: `$expired = ( ( time() - strtotime(get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ) / DAY_IN_SECONDS ) >= 5;`

Comment: @SamuelElh why not add it as an answer and explain what it is doing?

Comment: If either of our answers helped you solve this then please do accept one.  @SamuelElh 's is better and fuller than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing strings. For dates this will only ever work out if you use a yyyymmdd format or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Up-voting Andy's answer, you should be comparing integers to get this working. [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can turn any string to the time integer, which will be compared later to tell the difference and how many seconds passed until now ( `time()` ). Something like follows:

```
$expired = ( ( time() - strtotime(get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) ) / DAY_IN_SECONDS ) >= 5;
if ( $expired ) { 
    echo 'post expired'; 
} else { 
    echo 'post open'; 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Up vote back for the bit I was feeling to lazy to do :-)